# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to "my_url" after 1013 ms: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: php, php-curl

I was trying toget response from live server api in my local machine it runs perfect but when I am goiung live I found this error. Is there any solution of this

$response = Http::get('http://dev.biztekapps.com:8080/UltimatePOS-V4.7.2/UltimatePOS-V4.7.2/public/api/helloo');

dd($a->body());

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Usually web servers use port 80 or 443 for ssl. Your api call seems to be done using port 8080 is it wanted ? Did you try to access the API from your browser and from your code ? what's the response ?

Comment: same response i get on the other browser and in case of change my port its not working
""